# c# return interface type from method

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have 2 interfaces defined like this

```
public interface IEnumerableDisposable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IDisposable
{
}

public interface IApiCollection
{
    IEnumerableDisposable<TItem> GetItems<TItem>();
}
```

and a method that needs to return the first interface type like this

```
public IEnumerableDisposable<TItem> GetItems<TItem>()
```

where TItem can be either type Foo or type Bar

Question how do i cast the return type to IEnumerableDisposable ?

My understanding is that i need  class

```
public class EnumandDisposeFoo : IEnumerableDisposable<Foo>
{
}
```

and instaciate this class inside my method. how would i then cast the type back to its generic form?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
  var foo = new EnumandDisposeFoo(_pagedApi);

           var fooitems  = foo.GetEnumerator();

             return foo;  --> errors with

    Cannot implicitly convert type 'ApiCollection.Implementation.EnumandDisposeFoo' to 'ApiCollection.IEnumerableDisposable<TItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?
```

Comment: You don't need to "cast the type back to its generic form."  Just return your `EnumandDisposeFoo` instance; it already implements the interface you are returning.

Comment: You don't cast to the generic form - you shouldn't have to cast at all, `EnumandDisposeFoo` should be assignment compatible with `IEnumerableDisposable<Foo>`.

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey and Netmage much appreciated , i think im on the right track. Please see the line where my return type is not correct.

Comment: “where TItem can be either type Foo or type Bar”… as decided by… the implementer or the caller?

Comment: You should be returning an `EnumAndDispose<T>` where `T` is `Foo`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey , this works when is set the method signatrue to public IEnumerableDisposable<Foo> GetItems<TItem>() but not For TItem. I just dont know generics that well. Titem is decided by the Caller if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your code perhaps look similar?
I tried to derive it from the provided error message...

```cs
public IEnumerableDisposable<TItem> GetItems<TItem>()
{
    var foo = new EnumandDisposeFoo(_pagedApi);
    // var fooitems  = foo.GetEnumerator(); // not used and is in fact of type `IEnumerator<Foo>`
    return foo;
}
```

If yes, `EnumandDisposeFoo` implements `IEnumerableDisposable<T>` while specifying the element type `T` as `Foo`. At this point it is **no longer generic**. Trying to cast (*implicitly*) to the generic `IEnumerableDisposable<TItem>` will fail unless you provide an override for that specific implicit cast.

I doubt you want that.

Either you change `EnumandDisposeFoo` to a generic implementation:

```cs
public class EnumandDisposeFoo<TItem> : IEnumerableDisposable<TItem> { }
```

or you limit your method to return the (non-generic) `IEnumerableDisposable<Foo>`.

The compiler doesn't know which kind of type you want to return, thus no error at compile time.
Calling your method with `GetItems<Foo>()` will probably succeed.
But calling your method with any other type than `Foo` for `TItem` will try an implicit cast at run-time which might or might not fail.